# Remove last Path from URL using .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to create a RewriteRule on my .htaccess file which removes the Path ("page-2") **if it's included** at the end of the URL. So for example:

```
http://myhost.com/path/page-2
```

should redirect to:

```
http://myhost.com/path
```

I've found a similar solution on SO:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /$1/page-2/ [L]
```

However it does not work for me. No redirection happens.
Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/page-2/?$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```